# Share Local storage between iframe and page in Firefox and Safari - Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, local-storage, postmessage

Could you please help with the following? domaina.com/parent.html includes an iframe with src=domainb.com/iframe.html.  When we click a button on domaina.com/parent.html, we pass a URL to the iframe using postMessage and localStorage.  We will have multiple buttons with different URLs. Then, we're redirected to domainb.com/iframe.html.  Then, we retrieve the URL from localStorage and we'll be redirected to that URL.  The following code works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox and Safari; I'm able to save the URL to localStorage from the iframe, but once I'm redirected to the iframe page, the URL is not in localStorage on domainb.com.  Adding query parameters is not an option.

parent.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parent Window</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="iframe-id" src="https://domainb.com/iframe.html" width="500" height="200">
    </iframe>

    <div class="button" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer">Click Me</div>



    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

            document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {

                setTimeout(() => {
                    const iframeDomain = 'https://domainb.com'; // Set the correct iframe domain here

                    const data = doSomethingToGetData();
                    const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id');

                    // Send data to the iframe to save
                    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
                        action: 'save',
                        key: 'myKey',
                        value: data
                    }, iframeDomain);

                    // Request data from the iframe
                    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
                        action: 'get',
                        key: 'myKey'
                    }, iframeDomain);

                    window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);

                    function messageHandler(event) {
                        console.log(event)
                        if (event.origin !== iframeDomain) {
                            return; // Reject messages from unknown origins
                        }

                        const { action, key, value } = event.data;
                        if (action == 'returnData') {
                            useData(key, value);
                        }
                    }

                    // Function to simulate getting data
                    function doSomethingToGetData() {
                        return "https://redirect.com";
                    }

                    // Function to handle the returned data from the iframe
                    function useData(key, value) {
                        console.log('Received Data Key:', key);
                        console.log('Received Data Value:', value);
                    }
location.href = 'https://domainb.com/iframe.html';

                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Iframe Window</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const domains = [
                "https://domaina.com", // Add parent domain to the whitelist
                "https://domainb.com"
            ];

            window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
            // Check if the page is the top-level window (not inside an iframe)
            if (window === window.top) {
                window.location.href = getDataFromLocalStorage("myKey");
            }

            function messageHandler(event) {
                if (!domains.includes(event.origin))
                    return;

                const { action, key } = event.data;

                if (action === 'save') {
                    const value = event.data.value;
                    saveDataToLocalStorage(key, value);
                } else if (action === 'get') {
                    const value = getDataFromLocalStorage(key);
                    event.source.postMessage({
                        action: 'returnData',
                        key,
                        value
                    }, event.origin);
                }
            }

            // Function to save data to localStorage
            function saveDataToLocalStorage(key, value) {
                window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
            }
            // Function to get data from localStorage
            function getDataFromLocalStorage(key) {
                const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
                return value ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: LocalStorage is compartmentalized by origin, there's no way you can share it. You can try [other means of communicating cross-origin between browser windows](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging) that work cross-origin.

Comment: What is `saveDataToLocalStorage("myKey", getDataFromLocalStorage("myKey"))` meant to achieve? And why do it in a `beforeunload` handler instead of just calling the function before navigating away?

Comment: "*We're redirected to domainb.com/iframe.html*" - do you want to redirect the parent page or the frame? Also, you say that after visiting that page you want to be redirected again, to the url that you previously stored in the localstorage - why so complicated, why not just redirect to that url directly? It's not clear what your objective is here.

Comment: I don't understand how this is working on Chrome. I think you designed the flow backwards, if you want to save data for the new loaded iFrame, why not send it to the parent to save it in its localStorage and pass it back to the newly loaded iFrame? The parent page is the common denominator here, why save it in the iFrame localStorage?

Comment: You have two `setTimeout(…, 2000)` calls that schedule tasks at the same time. My guess would be that the parent page navigates away, and terminates the iframe context, before the iframe can receive the message you sent. For proper synchronisation, send a message back after saving in the iframe's localstorage, and have the parent wait for that response before leaving the page.

Comment: @Touffy OP *does* use `postMessage` to communicate between the two origins

Comment: Have you tried adding debug logs and breakpoints? Are the lines you expect to execute (in particular `saveDataToLocalStorage()`) actually reached in the browsers where this doesn't work?

Comment: @Bergi - you're correct, I'll remove beforeunload. The functionality is complicated, but these are the requirements. Working on the other comments now.  Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi - revised the code.  what do you mean, "For proper synchronisation, send a message back after saving in the iframe's localstorage, and have the parent wait for that response before leaving the page."  The URL is stored in LocalStorage, but in Firefox and Safari, the value of the localStorage item is null once we're redirected to iframe.html

Comment: "*these are the requirements*" - no, I mean, what are the [actual requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? What problem are you attempting to solve with this complicated redirection dance?

Comment: "*The URL is stored in LocalStorage*" - how do you know, how did you confirm this?

Comment: It might be possible that [the iframe localstorage is treated like third-party cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67645164/1048572) and therefore cleaned when you leave the page (or actually, there are different versions of the storage depending on which first-party domain the iframe is embedded, iirc). So whether this works might depend on the privacy / tracking protection settings of the respective browser, which could explain why it works in Chrome but not Firefox or Safari for you.

Comment: @Bergi - the requirements are as follows:  when we click one of the buttons, we are directed to iframe.html, and then we are redirected to the URL retrieved from localStorage.  re. ""The URL is stored in LocalStorage" - how do you know, how did you confirm this?" I know that the URL is stored in localStorage, because I can see the item being saved in Firefox dev tools, localStorage

Comment: It's still not clear what goal you are trying to achieve by taking the detour instead of directly redirecting to the final target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to my own question:

on iframe.html added a postMessage with action 'dataSaved' to respond back to the parent that data has been saved:

```
//existing code
 if (action === 'save') {
    const value = event.data.value;
    saveDataToLocalStorage(key, value);
    // Respond back to the parent that data has been saved
    event.source.postMessage({
        action: 'dataSaved',
                 key,
                 value
   }, event.origin);
}
//existing code
```

on parent.html added a listener to navigate to the new URL after receiving the data:

```
//existing code
if (action == 'returnData') {
   useData(key, value);
} else if (action === 'dataSaved') {
   // After receiving data, navigate to the new URL
   location.href = value;
}
//existing code
```